# FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner: turn off recursive descent into sub-directories?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Versions:

```
Spring: 5.2.16.RELEASE
Spring Integrations: 5.3.9.RELEASE
macOS Big Sur: 11.6
```

I am using XML to set up the directory scanner `FileReadingMessageSource.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` like so:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="channelIn" directory="${channel.dir}" auto-create-directory="false" use-watch-service="true" filter="channelFilter" watch-events="CREATE,MODIFY">
  <int-file:nio-locker ref="channelLocker"/>
  <int:poller fixed-delay="${channel.polling.delay}" max-messages-per-poll="${channel.polling.maxmsgs}"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

with the following bean definitions:

```
<bean id="channelLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker"/>
<bean id="channelFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="SpreadSheets*.xls" />
      </bean>
      <bean id="filter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.LastModifiedFileListFilter">
        <property name="age" value="${channel.filter.age}" />
      </bean>
      <ref bean="persistentFilter" />
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="persistentFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataStore" />
  <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="" />
  <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="false" />
</bean>
```

If I look at logs for `org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource`, I notice that we register both the specified directory (ie, `${channel.dir}`) as well as any of its sub-directories.  That is, I see logs like this:

```
15:44:45.706 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - registering: /Users/kc/scan.here for file events
15:44:45.711 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource - registering: /Users/kc/scan.here/and.here for file events
```

I've looked Spring docs as well as API docs for the relevant software modules (Eg, `FileReadingMessageSource`), but I don't see any property or configuration option for turning off recursive descent into sub-directories.

What is the recommended practice here for scanning only files within the specified directory, but not recursing any deeper than that?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't a recursion and scan the whole file tree, just don't use that watch service!

For the create and modify events you can configure a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which checks for the `file.lastModified()`. I see you do that anyway, therefore it is not clear why do you need a watch service at all?

See some related discussed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3557.

If you still have some reasonable argument to use watch service for only a root dir, please add a comment into that issue and we will revise it respectively.

Comment: Are you saying I can set `use-watch-service=false` but still see message-events in the specified directory that correspond to new files and/or modifications?  I would agree that should suffice for my needs; I will try that.  Still, I do think a wholesale recursion by default for the watch-service seems like overkill.

Comment: As I said: add such a comment into that issue - and we will revise it in the future.