# SourcePollingChannelAdapter: can inception of polling trigger after application start by arbitrary delay?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Versions:

```
Spring: 5.2.16.RELEASE
Spring Integrations: 5.3.9.RELEASE
macOS Big Sur: 11.6
```

For a fuller account of my `spring-integration` configuration, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817931/filereadingmessagesource-watchservicedirectoryscanner-turn-off-recursive-descen) I posted yesterday.

To sum up, I have set up this channel for polling changes to a directory:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="channelIn" directory="${channel.dir}" auto-create-directory="false" use-watch-service="false" filter="channelFilter" watch-events="CREATE,MODIFY">
  <int-file:nio-locker ref="channelLocker"/>
  <int:poller fixed-delay="${channel.polling.delay}" max-messages-per-poll="${channel.polling.maxmsgs}"></int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

It works fine.  However, there does not appear to be a configuration option to start the polling after application-start by some arbitrary delay.  In my case, I don't think there is any program error (yet) in starting the polling service immediately after Tomcat container starts my war-file.  But it is also true that there is quite a bit going on during the application-start, and my preference would be to defer the inception of the polling service some time after the bean for `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is created.

Is there anyway to do this in Spring?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) a couple of options:

1. Instead of `fixed-delay`, use the `trigger` property to point to a `PeriodicTrigger` bean with an `initialDelay` (and `fixedDelay`).
2. Set `auto-startup="false"` and start the adapter manually either directly, or using a control bus.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#control-bus

Comment: Works beautifully.  Thx.