# FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter: flushing policy that differs from flushOnUpdate?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

For my `spring-integration` setup, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69817931/filereadingmessagesource-watchservicedirectoryscanner-turn-off-recursive-descen), which I posted yesterday.  The relevant point is that I am using `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`; the `metadataStore` is PostgreSQL.
So far, the filter works as expected; filenames and timestamps are properly archived in the `metadataStore`.

My concern now is that over time, the `metadataStore` will grow, and that without a flushing policy, it will grow unbounded.  The built-in flushing policy for `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` seems to be rather limited:  ie, you can request that on updates to the `metadataStore` that it be flushed.  I fear, however, that that policy may result in missed files for my use-case.

Is there any way to support a different flushing policy for the `metadataStore` within my Spring app?  I suppose one option is to use the Spring scheduler and just periodically flush records in the `metadataStore` with a timestamp beyond a certain age.  But I was really hoping there might be a pre-packaged way to do this in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the meaning of `Flushable` - it has nothing to do with expiring store entries; it is for stores that keep data in memory - such as the `PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore` - by default, that store only writes the entries to disk when the application context is closed normally; flushing on each update persists to disk whenever the store changes.

There is no out of the box mechanism for removing old entries from metadata stores.